# Include supporting files in .NET referenced project published output

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a .NET Core MVC 2.0 solution which includes a number of "netstandard20" class libraries. One of these libraries, call it Services, uses PhantomJS to build PDFs from URLs.

In my Web project I am referencing the Services project and when I publish the solution I am getting the DLL output, but not the PhantomJS executables.

How do I tell MSBuild/csproj to include these files without tying Web to PhantomJS directly? - I only want to reference the Services project.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the items in the library also carry the `CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"` metadata, they should be automatically included in the published output of referenced projects. (`CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"` enables it to also be in the normal build output).

For example, if you add an `example.txt` file to the directory of a .NET Standard project, it will be shown in the project automatically. To make sure that the item is copied to build and publish outputs of referencing projects, you can add this to the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="example.txt" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

The property window should also show these options for the file.